# CoImpersonateClient causes CreateFileW to fail

Tags: c++, winapi, com, impersonation

I am working in a client/server scenario. I have a COM-based server which is running on the same machine as the client (the server is running as admin).

Anyways, there is a specific method in the server application which opens a file with `CreateFileW`. This is some pseudocode that makes up the call.

```
HRESULT __fastcall CxChmCallback::ParseQueryFile(CxChmCallback* this, wchar_t const* lpFileName, ...)
{
    if (FAILED(CoImpersonateClient())
        return E_FAIL;
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(lpFileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    CoRevertToSelf();
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return (HRESULT)-1;
    ...
}
```

Now, I *know* `CreateFileW` works because if I skip the call to `CoImpersonateClient()`, the function succeeds. Otherwise, the function fails and `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL (1364)`.

The client is running as a standard user with a medium integrity level, under a user account in the Administrators group. I have tried testing this with the client running as admin, but I get the same problem. Is there anything special about `CreateFileW` which causes it to fail?

Comment: Where is the code that is checking `GetLastError()`?  It needs to be called *immediately* after `CreateFileW()` fails, *before* `CoRevertToSelf()` is called, otherwise the error code from `CreateFileW()` can be lost before you retrieve it. BTW, `(HRESULT)-1` is not a very useful error code (ie, its a malformed `HRESULT` value).  I would suggest using `return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(errCode)` instead, where `errCode` is the (properly retreived) error code from `GetLastError()`. It would also be useful to return the actual `HRESULT` that `CoImpersonateClient()` returns on failure, instead of `E_FAIL`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Unfortunately, the server is not my code. I am using API Monitor to hook `CreateFileW` and calls `GetLastError()` on call failure. This is part of a personal reverse-engineering project of mine, and I am trying to use the `CxChmCallback::ParseQueryFile` function in my client.

Comment: *STATUS_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL* usually mean that token have *SecurityIdentification* impersonation level. this can be if say process have no impersonation privilege but try impersonate. under which privilege run your server ? it have impersonation privilege enabled ?

Comment: also - are client call `CoInitializeSecurity` - if yes - with what parameters (*dwImpLevel* is what)

Comment: @RbMm Server is running as same user as client, but elevated (administrator) -- high integrity level. Also server has impersonation privilege enabled. Also, my client is not calling `CoInitializeSecurity()`

Comment: @RbMm OK, I used `CoInitializeSecurity()` in my client and it worked, thanks. Can you make that an answer?

Comment: @ArushAgarampur You can also answer your own question for sharing your solution which will be helpful for others are searching on similar issue.